# The Grand Grid II

Tags: cipher, visual, logic-grid

[Have a look at the first Grand Grid to get an idea of the basic concept](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86584/the-grand-grid-i)

Each Grand Grid involves you discovering clues that allow you to solve a logic grid puzzle. The second in this series will be just like the first, except not at all, because this time the clues are entirely obscured in the Runescape map.

I won't be able to provide transcripts this time as part of the challenge is working out what the actual text is.

The image gets scaled down on this site. You will need to view the image in hi-res [here](https://i.ibb.co/z2j230K/Runescape-Map.png).

[Here is an album of images with the map split into 32 sections](https://ibb.co/album/d8zcyv)

[image]

There are six clues to find. I expect that this will require a group effort.

Join the Grand Grid chat to discuss it.

Due to @Annosz's fantastic progress and thinking that the script used for both of the last clues is harder to find the official version of than I intended (and if you don't have them it becomes very difficult indeed), I have decided to redo them in English:

Fourth Clue (As ordered by @Annosz)

> FLTTHEMILHHSPERRERAUAAEIEFZBXLRETZCIEGMELDSAAOREEWSMNTGFIEETHAG

Fifth Clue (As ordered by @Annosz)

> ACBBBBCBCDCBACABABCACBBCAAACABCDCAABCBACAACBCDCBBCBBBCDCABBBCBCBBCABCAABCDCABBCBCBBBACBCBABBCAAACBAABCBCABBCDCABBBCABAACDCBAABCBACBABCBACABBCAAACABBA

By the way

> The script was Liron. I couldn't remember what it was at the time of posting the above transliterations so did the cipher again with a different key. https://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/liron.php

Comment: the hi-res image still has a resolution to decipher the clue found. would you mind cropping the image into several pieces and uploading them here please? thanks and a +1 from me!

Comment: Sure I'll do that because that seems like a good idea for convenience but you should definitely be able to view the image in max resolution from that link (it is pixel perfect, the same resolution that the official Runescape map is in)... you might need to click to get the magnified version. Or you could save it and view it in a program like Paint :) And to be clear, the image embedded in the question is not the hi res version.

Comment: Ah well maybe it is necessary to show smaller parts... that part is unambiguous on my browser (Chrome) but browsers can be unreliable in how they show images.

Comment: It may also be that you are expecting that part to be clearer than it needs to be; anyway, I'll post the image split up.

Comment: and is there multi-layer cipher? i mean, for example, a rot 13 on top of atbash?

Comment: No, it may be additionally obscured but there is at most one cipher involved in each clue

Comment: Actually, if you can't identify a particular script, it may be possible that it would effectively have an additional substitution layer... but all the scripts involved are identifiable as having an official solution

Comment: Is this also a `knowledge` puzzle?  Do we need to know Runescape to get the full answer?

Comment: No, other than that a Runescape player might more easily recognise that something doesn't belong on the map, without having to directly compare it with the official Runescape map.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The six hint are highlighted in this image:**

> [image: All hints] 
>  
>  This can be extracted by getting the differences of Joshua's and the original Runescape map.

**First hint:**

> Left-down corner, in the sea 
>  
>  [image: First hint] 
>  
>  This is a simple rot17 cypher, which hides the following message (with spaces added):
>  
>  FIVE GAME DEVELOPERS ARE EACH DEVELOPING A PC GAME THEY AGREED TO FOCUSON DIFFERENT GENRES AND RELEASE THEIR GAMES ON DIFFERENT MONTHS THE DEVELOPERS ARE PARADOX BETHESDA KONAMI ROCKSTAR AND FIRAXIS THE MONTHS ARE APRIL TO AUGUST THE GENRES ARE ACTION STRATEGY PUZZLE SIMULATION AND ROLEPLAYING THE ROLEPLAYING GAME WILL BE RELEASED THREE MONTHS BEFORE THE PARADOX GAME

**Second hint:**

> Letters at the Shamans region: 
>  
>  [image: Second hint] 
>  
>  This is written with [Daedric alphabet](https://lingojam.com/DaedricAlphabet), and translates to the following (with spaces added): 
>  THE ROLEPLAYING GAME IS NOT BEING DEVELOPED BY KINAMI

**Third hint:**

> Letters at the Prifddinas region: 
>  
>  [image: Third hint] 
>  
>  I don't know the alphabet here, but from the previous hint I suspected that the word 'developed' will be present. I searched for the pattern, and when I fount it, I started replacing letters and backtracking. The decoded message (with spaces added) is: 
>  THE PUZZLE GAME IS EITHER THE ONE THAT IS BEING RELEASED IN MAY OR IS BEING DEVELOPED BY BETHESDA

**Fourth hint - solved by @Jens**

> Letters on the mountain: 
>  
>  [image: Fourth hint] 
>  
>  @Joshua Bizley gave the following translation: 
>  FLTTHEMILHHSPERRERAUAAEIEFZBXLRETZCIEGMELDSAAOREEWSMNTGFIEETHAG 
>  And by @Jens's work we found that if we take every 7th letter we get the following message: 
>  FIRAXIS WILL RELEASE THEIR GAME THREE MONTHS AFTER THE PUZZLE GAME ABCDEFG

**Fifth hint: - solved by @Jens**

> Letters near Ice Path: 
>  
>  [image: Fifth hint 2] 
>  
>  @Joshua Bizley gave the following translation: 
>  ACBBBBCBCDCBACABABCACBBCAAACABCDCAABCBACAACBCDCBBCBBBCDCABBBCBCBBCABCAABCDCABBCBCBBBACBCBABBCAAACBAABCBCABBCDCABBBCABAACDCBAABCBACBABCBACABBCAAACABBA 
>  And @Jens found the solution (the method is written in his answer, make sure upvote it too!) 
>  THE ACTION GAME IS BEING DEVELOPED BY PARADOX

**Sixth hint:**

> The names of some places has been replaced/expanded. This gives us the following list: 
>  Esp Cove, Mp Pass, Cpwpidpo River, Htww (Outpost), Rlxp Jungle, Dtxfwletzy Hills, Ty Tower, Ufwj Village 
>  
>  If you put these names in alphabetical order by their suffix / area name, you get the following text: 
>  EspDtxfwletzyRlxpHtwwMpCpwpidpoTyUfwj 
>  
>  Which is a ROT for the following question: 
>  **The simulation game will be released in july**

**The final solution and the logic grid is the following:**

> [image: Logic grid]

Comment: Nice work Annosz! For hint 6, ignore the bracket and it will alphabetise into the order of a statement rather than a question...

Comment: Very impressive! I can confirm that you can see everything in the characters near Ice Path. There are only four different characters. Looks like the second image distinguishes them all well.

Comment: @Stiv thank you. I skipped Outpost, because it is not present on the picture as a difference between the original and the edited, but I guess it makes more sense that way.

Comment: I think the "official" translation of the script you haven't solved yet is harder to find than I intended. I will update the question later with the remaining ciphertexts in English, both of which still require deciphering at that point.

Comment: The fourth hint translates to Rot13(SVENKVF JVYY ERYRNFR GURVE TNZR GUERR ZBAGUF NSGRE GUR CHMMYR TNZR NOPQRST. Whfg gnxr rirel 7gu yrgre fgnegvat jvgu gur svefg.)

Answer (score 6):

I've solved the fifth hint, but it's a bit long for a comment:

> The cipher is 
>  ACBBBBCBCDCBACABABCACBBCAAACABCDCAABCBACAACBCDCBBCBBBCDCABBBCBCBBCABCAABCDCABBCBCBBBACBCBABBCAAACBAABCBCABBCDCABBBCABAACDCBAABCBACBABCBACABBCAAACABBA 
>  
>  If the D's are spaces between words, and the C's are separators between letters, we get 
>  A-BBBB-B BA-ABAB-A-BB-AAA-AB AAB-BA-AA-B BB-BBB ABBB-B-BB-AB-AAB ABB-B-BBBA-B-BABB-AAA-BAAB-B-ABB ABBB-ABAA BAAB-BA-BAB-BA-ABB-AAA-ABBA 
>  
>  I assumed the word GAME was somewhere in the message and since there was only one four-letter word (AAB-BA-AA-B), that must be it. Some more trial and error gives the following clear text: 
>  
>  THE ACTION GAME IS BEING DEVELOPED BY PARADOX

One viable solution to the logic grid occurs if we guess that

> Bethesda is releasing in June. But I haven't checked if other solutions are possible. Perhaps a last clue is needed? I'll let @Annosz wrap up the puzzle since he did the vast majority of the work! :).

**EDIT**

The last comment above is wrong. There is only one solution. I leave it to you, @Annosz. :)

Comment: And this is Morse Code.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Ahh...thanks! I just assumed it was some coding scheme invented by the OP.